# Delete a file from firebase/google cloud storage with the file url in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a file url link and I want to delete it from firebase cloud functions (node js).

```
module.exports.makeLinkInvalid = async (url) => {
  if (url) {
    const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
    const storage = new Storage();
    const projectId = process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
    console.log(projectId);
    const bucketurl = `${projectId}.appspot.com`;
    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketurl);

    const file = bucket.file("images/~0FcNki1XqdruX-ZKzGCB.png");
    await file.delete();
  }
};
```

I tried projectId with appspot.com and without it. I tried adding a slash before the file path and without it. I tried creating bucketful starting with `gs://` but every time i get the same error `No such object: my-project.appspot.com/images/~0FcNki1XqdruX-ZKzGCB.png`

My requirement is that I need a function that will take a URL and then create a path from it, then it will just delete the file on that path.

I tried using `firebase-admin storage` but that yields the same result.
Right now I am giving it a file path hard-coded, but no luck.

Bucket structure.
[image]

Comment: What is the `givePathFromLink()` function?

Comment: Ignore that. I have edited the question please check now. I am passing a hard-coded path to ```bucket.file()```

Comment: Have you made sure that the `projectId` and `path` is correct? and also, could you also provide a screenshot of your bucket that contains the specific location of the file that you want to delete.

Comment: The project name is correct I logged it multiple times to verify it. I am attaching the bucket screenshot in the question

Comment: I'm still not seeing the `png file` you're pertaining to your screenshot. Check if `7ugbez8AbsOhDEKrz5Imh.png` is still on your bucket.

Comment: Yes the file is in the bucket but for the sake of this screenshot let's just consider the shown in the screenshot ```~0FcNki1XqdruX-ZKzGCB.png```

Comment: I have updated the question as well